# What are synonyms for Chieftain?

Tags: synonyms

I've wondered if there are many synonyms for chieftain because I can't think of any.

Comment: Here are [232 of them](https://www.powerthesaurus.org/chieftain). Did you attempt to search for an answer to your question using the internet first?

Comment: I did, yet I only found two that worked with what I needed to say... but thanks anyway.

Comment: Can you can elaborate on the specific usage that you are hoping to address? It would help to know which words you have already considered and why they do not fit so that better options may be suggested.

Comment: A chieftain of Iceland to be specific, one of the Gođi.

Comment: I doubt there are *any* English words that specifically mean *Icelandic chieftain* . . .

Comment: Back in the Middle Ages, there was a French noun/title, "captal", that would be the equivalent (more or less) of the English noun/title "chieftain".

Comment: There's this thing called a "thesaurus".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked around for descriptions of the duties for such an Icelandic chieftain.  I found the duties of the office to be rather nebulous, but seemed to fit within the English words - leader, governor, and priest. Or, to put it another way "One who is in charge of" various duties that encompassed civic, legal, and spiritual responsibilities. Possibly the original word "chieftain", which is from the English word "captain", expresses this vague leadership role the best.